# Include error.h head file gives me an error in c

Tags: c

```
#include <error.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

gives me the error

```
fatal error: error.h: No such file or directory
```

Can compile successfully when I remove `#include <error.h>`

Comment: There is no `error.h` in the standard C library system. Perhaps you are looking for `errno.h`?

Comment: I believe `error.h` defines things that are GNU extensions (e.g. `error`, `error_at_line`, etc.).  If you're not using glibc/gcc then they're probably not available.

Comment: @AdrianMole  I think the source code has a line ```if (argc < 2) error(1, 0, "missing argument")```, that's where it needs the ```error.h```file

Comment: @TomKarzes well, I think I'm using gcc by writing ```gcc -g -O0 -std=gnu99 -Wall $warnflags  parity.c  -o parity```, I'm new to c, where did I do wrong..

Comment: @Bubblethan Ok, if you're using `gcc` and not getting `error.h`, then it sounds like you have an incomplete glibc installation.  Or perhaps you're on a non-Linux system?  I don't know if it's included in Windows installs.  With a standard Linux installation (e.g., Ubuntu) it should be `/usr/include/error.h`

Comment: @TomKarzes No, I'm on macOS, I don't think i have a ```/usr/include/error.h``` directory.

Comment: Hm, it looks like `gcc` installations on many non-Linux platforms are missing it for some reason.  I was able to find [this description](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/error_002eh.html).  You could try to install gnulib.  You can find some [instructions here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/).  That might fix it, but I have not tried it myself.  The easiest thing would be to remove the non-portable code stick to pure ISO C.

Comment: If the code compiles without warnings when you don't include `<error.h>`, then you don't need the header.  If it compiles with warnings about missing declarations for functions, it wasn't really successful — assuming you want to adhere to a more modern standard than C90.  C99 and later versions require functions to be declared before use.  If you use functions without a prior declaration, you should get compiler warnings (unless the compiler only enforces C90 semantics, in which case you should upgrade your compiler).